# JSF mapping properties to list in action class

Tags: jsf, properties, action

I have a list of employee details in my action class. I am showing them in dataTable in JSF. And allowing User to edit the properties.

I want to map all those properties and objects to the list in action class.
I tried using managed property...but I want how that properties can be passed from JSP page.
How can that be achieved in JSF?

```
//faces-config
                 <managed-bean>
       <managed-bean-name>employeeProps</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>com.test.EmployeePropertiesBean</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
  <managed-property>
            <property-name>emplyeeList</property-name>
            <property-class>java.util.ArrayList</property-class>
            <value>#{emplyeeList}</value>
  </managed-property>
 </managed-bean>
 // Navigation rule configured and works well



 //Action clss
public class EmployeePropertiesBean
{

    private List<Exmployee> emplyeeList = new ArrayList<Exmployee>(); //with getter setters
    .
    .
    .
}



//JSP page
<h:dataTable value="#{employeeProps.emplyeeList}" var="employeePropEntry" >

<h:inputText value="#{advancedPropEntry.value}" id="propText" rendered="#{employeePropEntry.type=='text'}">
.
.
.
.
// Trying to populated the Employee list properties using below the but not working... Similar stuff works with Struts
<h:inputHidden id="emplyeeList[0].name" value="#{employeePropEntry.name}"></h:inputHidden>


</h:dataTable>
```

Comment: Show us relevant parts of your code.

Comment: You should read up on the proper use of the dataTable component in JSF.  It should contain column children components and your other components belong in a column.  Secondly, `id="emplyeeList[0].name"` is not a valid ID.  This is supposed to be a unique value that represents this component on the page and the server.  I suggest that you find a good book on JSF and try to master the basics first because it is very different from Struts.